# Is it possible to use self-referential associated types when using generics?

Tags: generics, rust, traits, associated-types

Example: given the following trait,

```
trait DirectedAcyclicGraph<V, E> where V: Add, E: Add
```

I would like for whenever a value of the type `V` to a value of the same type that another value of type `V` is returned. Whenever a value of type `E` is added to another value of the same type I want another `E` to be returned.

Naively, I thought that this might be in the right direction,

```
trait DirectedAcyclicGraph<V, E> where V: Add<Output = V>, E: Add<Output = E>
```

but that was just a shot in the dark.

The documentation for `Add` supplies the following example,

```
use std::ops::Add;

struct Foo;

impl Add for Foo {
    type Output = Foo;

    fn add(self, _rhs: Foo) -> Foo {
        println!("Adding!");
        self
    }
}

fn main() {
    Foo + Foo;
}
```

but I cannot understand how to provide an implementation for a generic type in the same way, if that is even possible.

Comment: Did you *try* what you thought might be in the right direction? It looks correct to me.

Comment: Yes, did not work. On a cell now. I can follow up with the related error later

Comment: Thanks, now it works. I had missed adding the `Output =` at a particular implementer of the trait which caused a lot of errors in the compiler output so I simply missed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being a case of a programming error. As @ChrisMorgan pointed out [in his example](http://is.gd/9qyS95), the expression `Add<Output = V>` does compile. The reason the compiler wailed was that in one location in the production source-code `Output = V` had not been consistently added.

Regrettably I must have also made some error when compiling the condensed MWE.

So, the take-away for posterity is that

```
trait DirectedAcyclicGraph<V, E> where V: Add<Output = V>, E: Add<Output = E>
```

works.